# Google Maps View Android extra margin without tiles

Tags: google-maps, unity-game-engine, google-maps-android-api-2

I am experiencing this white margin where tiles are missing only on some devices like Huawei with a 16:9 screen like the P20 Smart. You can see that the view size is correct as the buttons are placed correctly just the tiles are not loaded correctly. I am pretty sure it's some internal issue of Google Maps SDK but any clues how to fix it would be appreciated.

The view is shown as a dialog on top of Unity game.

[image: Bug]

Comment: UPD - Updated image to better show the issue

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, you can set size of your map view larger then screen and use [Map padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding) for correct placing of map controls and Google logo. Something like that:

[image: Map padding]

Updated explanation

[image: Map padding 2]

For "small view in the middle of the screen" that small view should have parent layout for hiding invisible areas:

[image: Map padding 3]

Comment: Thanks, I know about this workaround and it works fine when the map needs to be fullscreen but if you want to display a small view in the middle of the screen that won't work.

Comment: @TarasLeskiv Hmm, actually it's possible to create MapView (MapFragment) with any size (in dp or pixels).

Comment: yes, but that's where whites space on the bottom and right appears that I don't know how to get rid of

Comment: @TarasLeskiv So, set the size of MapView larger than view port. White spaces should go outside view port, to invisible area in that case. In that case required to show "Google" sign and map controls ("+/-" buttons and current location button) also goes to invisible area, but you can return them back with [Map Padding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/map#map_padding). So use padding not for map padding itself, but for returning back Google logo and map controls.